# Any way to get a more meaningful error message in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.6

Let's have some tea ...

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION allRelevantTeas() RETURNS TABLE(tea_id INTEGER) AS $function$
DECLARE
    result REFCURSOR;
    stmt TEXT;
    countries_with_tea TEXT[] := array['england', 'turkey', 'india', 'japan', 'china'];
BEGIN
    stmt := '';
    FOR tea_drinker in countries_with_tea LOOP
        stmt := stmt || format($$(SELECT tea_id FROM %I)$$, tea_drinker);
        IF tea_drinker <> 'china' THEN
            stmt := stmt || $$ UNION $$;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    OPEN result FOR EXECUTE stmt;
    RETURN result;
END $function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;

SELECT * FROM allRelevantTeas();
```

Let's test this ...

> syntax error at or near "countries_with_tea"

I don't see it. It's probably quite obvious, but I just don't see it.

Does anybody spot what's wrong with this? Or if not, is there any way I can get a more meaningful error from postgres than "there was a syntax error (but I don't tell you what it was)"?

Comment: The fact that you have one table for each country seems like a really strange database design.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no argument there. Obviously I changed the names for this example, but basically, somebody decided that `country` should be a mapped superclass, so here we are ...

Comment: I have corrected the first eror and now you have a new one. Here you can play with it :) : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f12e39cc12b6732a405cdb94d42baee7

Comment: Btw: I would at least use `return execute query execute stmt;` and get rid of the refcursor

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, but that leads to the same issue as the refcursor thing ... `ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop over the is wrong, you need to use `FOREACH` to [loop through the elements of an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION allRelevantTeas() RETURNS TABLE(tea_id INTEGER) AS $function$
DECLARE
    stmt TEXT;
    tea_drinker text;
    countries_with_tea TEXT[] := array['england', 'turkey', 'india', 'japan', 'china'];
BEGIN
    stmt := '';
    FOREACH tea_drinker in array countries_with_tea LOOP
        stmt := stmt || format($$(SELECT tea_id FROM %I)$$, tea_drinker);
        IF tea_drinker <> 'china' THEN
            stmt := stmt || $$ UNION $$;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN query execute stmt;
END $function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

You don't really need a UNION, you can use `return query` to return multiple results:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION allrelevantteas() 
  RETURNS TABLE(tea_id INTEGER) AS $function$
DECLARE
    stmt TEXT;
    tea_drinker text;
    countries_with_tea TEXT[] := array['england', 'turkey', 'india', 'japan', 'china'];
BEGIN
    stmt := '';
    FOREACH tea_drinker in array countries_with_tea LOOP
      stmt := format($$(SELECT tea_id FROM %I)$$, tea_drinker);
      return query execute stmt;
    END LOOP;
END $function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=563022c9608b28292cc10015bfcd97e4)

---

If you need that a log, it might be better to use table inheritance or a view to create a single table that contains all others.

Comment: `forEACH` , not `for` ... I feel stupid, now. But thanks a lot. :) I also didn't know you could return multiple queries in a loop. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small off hand note. I often look at my code and ask "Is there anything that is subject to breaking at any foreseeable change and can I prevent it now?" It has  served my well for many years, and I almost always can find something. There is one here. The statement "If tea_drinker ... end if" is very fragile. What happens when another country is added to the array and gets added after China. Answer, your SQL fails when executed. A hardened version would be to check the position of the current tea_drinker to the last enter in the array. This can be done with the [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html), array_position and array_length.

```
-- Instead of: 
IF tea_drinker <> 'china' THEN
   stmt := stmt || $$ UNION $$;
END IF;

-- Use 
if array_position(countries_with_tea, tea_drinker) <> array_length(countries_with_tea, 1)
then 
   stmt := stmt || $$ UNION $$;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

a_horse_with_no_name has told you how to fix the error, but for getting a more meaningful error message, I already get one, using psql:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "countries_with_tea"
LINE 8:     FOR tea_drinker in countries_with_tea LOOP
                               ^
```

If your only see you the first line and not the next two, then you are using some tool which is not your friend.